# mysql and table configuration

Tags: mysql, query-performance

```
select id from test_table where active = 1;
update test_table set a="b", c="d", e="1";
insert into test_table (column1, column2, column3, ...) VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

I am trying to do a lot of work with mysql, but I would like to ask about the table configuration.
There is a test table, and rows are getting stacked up here. Because it is being inserted over time.
We then 'select' this row and continue to 'update' this row.
However, this row is growing more than a million times, slowing down.
I have upgraded the server specification, but there are many cases where the server is down.
So let's ask how to handle this case.

My idea is to partition the mysql table. I have not tried it, but I think it is the most likely.
But I have not tried it yet, and I do not know if this is the right way.

In summary, there are more than one million rows in the current test table, and more rows are inserted in the future. And we continue to 'select' and 'update'. In this case, should there be any other way to improve the speed of data processing than to increase the specs (I have upgraded the performance of the server a lot, so I am looking for another way). What internal improvements should I make to improve speed? How do we change the structure?
I would be very grateful to let you know by example of the source code.

Comment: Do you have indexing ?

Comment: The three queries don't seem to have anything to do with each other??  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.